# A functional equation ( old title new question)

Tags: functions

I have the following functional equation: $f'(a/x) = x/f(x)$  where a is a positive real number and f(x) has a domain and codomain of positive real numbers.

By assuming a $g(x)=f(x)×f(a/x)$ ,I got till the result
$f(x)×f(a/x) = b$ (constant) ,(using the derivative of g)  ,but am unable to solve it further for $f(x)$. What should possibly be a next step ?

Comment: Sorry I can't derive this, but by guesswork, $f(x)=\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}x$ seems to be a solution...

Comment: It does satisfy it but there is a more general solution existing as well,  √b ((x/√a)^b/a) is the given function . Moreover I would appreciate the method to get to the function

Comment: Using $g(x)=b$, you can find $f'(x)=\frac{a/x}{f(a/x)}=\frac{af(x)}{bx}$. Then you can solve ODE.

Comment: Oh, I see now. Thank you for your time